# How Do I Prepend Concatenated Elements With Options in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dom

I want to prepend multiple, concatenated elements to a parent element in jQuery, with the cleanest code I can use. Right now, I'm prepending a new element to a parent, like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("<div>", {
  class: "some-class another-class"
})
.prependTo("#container");
```

**Resulting HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="some-class another-class">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to insert multiple concatinated elements this way, and apply classes and inner text to them in the most efficiant way possible. The final output should look something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="some-class another-class">
    text: <strong><em>text</em></strong>
    Some more text
    <button class="class-1 class-2 right"></button>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this with multiple elements, the same way I'm doing it with one element in my example above?

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeJunkie/KNq84/) of the beginning code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the `insertBefore` method:

```
$("<div>", { class: "some-class another-class" }).insertBefore("#container");
```

Here's the documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I know of:

```
$("<div />").addClass("some-class another-class")
    .html("text: <strong><em>text</em></strong>
        Some more text
        <button class="class-1 class-2 right"></button>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    ).appendTo('#container');
```